# Can I use FFMPEG to record ultra sonic?

Tags: ffmpeg

I use `av_dump_format()` to check information and I get

```
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536kb/s
```

Now I can record music, it's working well(I generated a pcm file to listen). However, in terms of ultra sonic, I can't record any useful audio information, so can I use FFmpeg to record ultra sonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To record ultra-sonic audio you first have to make sure your microphone and audio capture device are capable of handling these frequencies (standard equipment won't do this without severe attenuation). For FFmpeg all you need to do is choose a sample rate that is at least twice as high as the highest frequency you wish to record. Look up [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) if you want to understand why.

Comment: The hardware default sample rate is 48000Hz and the ultra-sonic audio I need to record is around 22000Hz so I don't think sample rate is the point but I'm not sure that the hardware can record ultra-sonic audio or not, I think maybe this is the point.

Comment: I changed the hardware and I succeeded to record ultra-sonic audio!